# Plausibility of a Dyson sphere

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, stability

So [Dyson spheres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_sphere) are generally considered implausible for two main reasons. One, it would an incredible amount (and type) of resources to build one. And two, a Dyson sphere would be unstable because if it was moved even slightly off center it would collapse into the star. These reasons are spelled out more thoroughly in countless articles, an example being: http://www.popularmechanics.com/space/deep-space/a11098/could-we-build-a-dyson-sphere-17110415/

So I have no problem with the first reason, but I'm curious about the second. So a Dyson would theoretically have an "equal" distribution of mass and uniform thickness. So couldn't shell theory be applied here? Shell theory states in a uniform spherical shell gravity can be calculated as though the mass was clustered at a single point. And objects within that shell do not have gravitational acceleration toward the shell's edges. So would the Dyson sphere actually fall into the star even budged a little bit? I'm assuming that shell theory works for gravity in both ways (on the star due to the shell and on the shell due to the star), which it should.

Comment: It stands to reason from Newton's 3rd law that if the star can feel no gravitational force from the shell, the shell can feel no gravitational force from the star. The math is worth doing, because this is an interesting point

Comment: It would have been awfully nice of you to include a short summary of the concept in the question.